# Where do I change current menu item highlight colour in CSS?

Tags: css

I am currently working on a website for a client using Joomla www.bisdynamics.com
On the desktop version of the site, on the main navigation for the current menu item, the link appears with a blue surround #0088cc. I have searched high and low in the template.css for where this is controlled but to no avail. I have also looked for the RGB version of this colour. Would any of you guys happen to know where I can find it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 9 of bootstrap.css you'll see this, which is your culprit.

```
.nav-pills > .active > a, .nav-pills > .active > a:hover, .nav-pills > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #0088CC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I changed #08c to #063 but the results are still the same :(

Comment: You haven't added the CSS to your template.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Its located in boostrap.min.css line 9

```
.nav-pills>.active>a, .nav-pills>.active>a:hover, .nav-pills > .active> a:focus{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #08C
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I changed #08c to #063 but the results are still the same :(